# Implementing reset button for countdown timer

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Hello guys as a beginner i have not learned yet how to write a good code, so it is not refactored one, and it is actually spagetti code. Anyway i want to learn to code, so in my project (i modify someone's code) i have two ways to set a timer:
1. By clicking a button on navigation menu, like in the picture below.
[image]
2. By inputing, like in the picture below.
[image]

The issue is i call timer function two times

```
reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
  timer(mins * 60);
  timer(seconds);
});
```

one for quick buttons

```
var quickTime = function() {
  seconds = parseInt(this.dataset.time);
  timer(seconds);
}

buttons.forEach((button) => button.addEventListener('click', quickTime));
```

and one for input.

```
buttons.forEach((button) => button.addEventListener('click', quickTime));
document.customFormSession.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  mins = this.minutesSession.value;
  displayTimerLeftSession(mins * 60);
  timer(mins * 60);
  this.reset();

});
```

And it makes sense why it does not work properly because one overrides another. I think one option would be check if a quick button has a particular class call timer(seconds), else call timer(mins*60). However i'm not sure if it will work, moreover i do not know how to implement it, and do not know where to put this code if it is indeed correct algorithm. Please if you know i would be glad to hear your suggestions. If you can implement it feel free to fork the [project](http://codepen.io/nazimkazim/pen/RKrJxq), it would be even more useful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to have the reset button to reset to the correct time for both methods of starting the timer?

**Summary and quick fix:**

Just add `seconds = mins * 60` to your `customFormSession` event listener:

```
document.customFormSession.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  mins = this.minutesSession.value;
  seconds = mins * 60
  displayTimerLeftSession(mins * 60);
  timer(mins * 60);
  this.reset();
});
```

**Explanation:**

You are simply storing the timer in a global variable called `seconds`. This variable is set for your quick time button click event listener but not for your form submit as stated in the summary.

To be honest, I don't think you even need the `mins` variable:

```
document.customFormSession.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  seconds = this.minutesSession.value * 60;
  displayTimerLeftSession(seconds);
  timer(seconds);
  this.reset();
});
```

My [fork of your project](http://codepen.io/nelsyeung/pen/bgeXRW)

Comment: Thanks it was so helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that takes the the timeout as an argument and returns a callback that starts the timer when it's called. Something like this:

```
var createTimerCallback = function (duration) {
    return function () {
        // Starts a timer for the duration seconds
    }
};
```

You need to attach the return value of this function to all "quick" buttons:

```
var durations = [5 * 60, 10 * 60, 15 * 60]; // Or any other constants you need
var buttons = ... // Your "quick" buttons
for (var i = 0; i < duration.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].on('click', createTimerCallback(duration[i])); 
}
```

This way, the duration get captured for each button and doesn't change.

You can keep handling the form the way you do it now: get the number of minutes from the input field and start a timer with the specified duration.

Comment: Thanks for reply i will definitely try your suggestion!